# Request a popular name for this or its solution algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Here is the problem together with the kind of result I am expecting.
I already have a routine that does this, I would like to research other solutions though so need any popular names for either a solutions or the problem itself.

```
If name1 and name2 are aliases or equivalent and name3 and name2 are aliases then
name1, name2, and name3 are all aliases of each other.

>>> aliases = [('name1', 'name2'), ('name3', 'name2')]
>>> consolidate_aliases(aliases)
[('name2', 'name3', 'name1')]
>>> aliases = [('A', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'), ('C', 'Z'), ('S', 'L'), ('T', 'M'), ('U', 'N'), ('Y', 'T'),  ('B', 'L')]
>>> consolidate_aliases(aliases)
[('S', 'B', 'T', 'Y', 'M', 'L'), ('U', 'N'), ('C', 'Z'), ('A', 'X')]
>>>
```

Comment: You do realize that most people who are not you will not have any idea what you are talking about, right?

Comment: Thanks Jon. The answers so far by Henrik and MBo below are interesting and touch on what I am after. (It would be nice if Wikipedia could try and make such admittedly technical subjects more approachable).

Comment: this like as Separate part of connectivity in graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a variant of the "Connected components of a graph" problem. Google for it to see answers  like [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2005/cmsc451/components.pdf) and [this](http://computation.pa.msu.edu/NO/ConnCompPresentation.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Union-Find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)